# how the borel subalgebras of p(n) look like except the standard one?

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-superalgebras

I am reading the book Musson: Lie superalgebras. In Chapter 3, on page 62, Lemma 3.6.8 tells about support of Borel subalgebra. I am confused about this.
I am trying to do the proof of the Proposition 3.6.11 part(a), which follows from Exercise 3.7.21 according to the book. But hint of exercise does not apply on the example given below Proposition 3.6.11 as {1,3} and {2,3}  give adjacent Borel subalgebras by proposition but according to Exercise 3.7.21 they are not adjacent as only different root in Borel of {1,3} is $\varepsilon_{1}+\varepsilon_{3}$ and in {2,3} is $-(\varepsilon_{1}+\varepsilon_{3})$, but all other roots in support of both are same.

Proposition 3.6.11. If $I$ and $J$ are two subsets of ${\{1,2,....,m}\}$  with $d(\mathfrak b_{I})= d(\mathfrak b_{J})+1$ , then 
(a) $\mathfrak b_{I}$ and $\mathfrak b_{J}$ are adjacent iff there exists $k  \in I$ such that $k+1 \in J$ and $ I \backslash {\{k}\}= J \backslash{\{k+1}\}$.

Exercise 3.7.21  show that $\mathfrak b$ and $\mathfrak b^{'}$ are adjacent iff there exists $k$ such that $\alpha =\pm (\varepsilon_{k} + \varepsilon_{k+1})$ is a root of $\mathfrak b$ , -$\alpha$ is a root of $\mathfrak b^{'}$, and apart from $\pm \alpha$, $\mathfrak b$ has the same roots as $\mathfrak b^{'}$.

Comment: Can you please say what are 3.6.11, 3.7.21, etc. People are more likely to help you if they don’t have to look up those things. (Also, less important, but if you could use capital letters it would be nice.)

Comment: Maybe it's more useful to contact Ian Musson by email?    In any case, it's a good idea to attach moe tags such as 'lie-algebras'.



I